# sharing books on kindle is not allowed

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

The loaning of books option is not allowed on all amazon sites. It seems like it is allowed only on the US site. I could not fin this restriction on their loan books documentation. Why is their such a restriction based on countries?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are not likely to be any answers other than speculative ones--the only answer is "because that it Amazon's business decision." As a business question, it is also not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200901300) This is due to geographical restrictions the Editor can impose into a book. BTW, this option is enabled in the Mexico site so it's not only on the US.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to read a translated version of the link :--).  The answer does make sense but I could not find this info easily.